# Recipes for Mead Jelly

Tags: mead

I have been making mead for awhile now, and I just came across Mead Jelly in the market.  The jelly was excellent on hard cheese, and I'm wondering if anyone has made it and would like to share their recipe...

Answer (score 2):

i just googled "mead jelly recipe"...   looks like you can just follow a normal jelly recipe (sugar, water, pectin), but replace some of the water with mead.    I imagine you could use pyment in a grape jelly to amp up the "grapeness" or a berry melomel in a berry jelly, etc.  (Cyser in apple butter?)

I've never tried it.

actually, you may have to adjust the pectin slightly.   I don't know how the alcohol in the mead with react with it (since it's generally 10-20% of the volume of a mead).

[mead jelly with roasted pears](http://uktv.co.uk/food/recipe/aid/640258)  (hmm...   that's british jelly, which is gelatin, and not a fruit spread...   I just realized that I don't know which you're actually looking for)

Answer (score 0):

I have make cocktail jellies, and Honey and citrus jellie before (British Jelly) with Gelatin, and I would guess you would follow a very similar recipe to the cocktail jellies:

For your pint of mead take 5-7 sheet of gelatin, about 25-50% more than the packet advises for a similar volume, to offset the denaturing qualities of the alcohol.

Dissolve in the gelatin to the warmed mead, then add to your jars and leave to set in the fridge.

If you are doing it with pectin then I'd suggest again the 25-50% extra to account for the alcohol which will affect setting.

Edit:

PS I will try this (British Jelly) and report back.